# Do "thousands of" and "millions of" mean the same?

Tags: meaning, numbers

In the website http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/thousand#thousand__2, I find that

> When you are not giving an exact number, you can use the plural form *"thousands"* with the preposition *"of"*:
>
> > Every day, thousands of tons of waste were sent to landfills.
>
> The words **hundred** and **million** work in the same way."

Do "thousands of" and "millions of" mean the same?

I kind of think the number that "millions of" refers to is more than the number that "thousands of" refers to.

Comment: Obviously it is more to talk about *"millions"* than *"thousands"* but if you are using this idiom, you are not bothered with quantity imho.

Comment: The example is discussing how you use the words… not how many items they refer to.

Comment: Both "millions of" and "thousands of" can refer to a large number of things or people, but the  quantity that the former refers to is more than that of the latter. Can I understand it this way?

Comment: I disagree with the quoted passage. If someone says "thousands of" something, I assume they have a reasonable expectation that the actual amount is between 1,000 and 9,999, inclusive. If someone says "millions of", I assume they have a reasonable expectation that the actual amount is between 1,000,000 and 9,999,999, inclusive, possibly extending to 999,999,999, but then I would expect to see "tens of millions of" or  "hundreds of millions of" for amounts 10,000,000 or greater. Likewise with "tens" or "hundreds of thousands of".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I kind of think the number that "millions of" refers to is more than the number that "thousands of" refers to.

You are correct.

Read the text carefully:

> The words *hundred* and *million* **work** in the same way.

*X works the same as Y* is not the same as saying *X means the same as Y*.

Answer (score 5):

It's not trying to teach you the meanings of the numbers at all….
it's trying to teach you  *( [unit]plural + 'of' )* is the way to convey your intended approximate quantity —

> There are *dozens of* recipes in the book & *scores of* photographs. It sold *millions of* copies, in *thousands of* stores, in *hundreds of* cities around the world.

It doesn't even need to be a straight 'count', it could be a distance…

> *Miles of* golden beaches stretched as far as the eye could see...
>   *Yards of* cloth were used to make the dress…

Or time…

> *Hours of* queuing to see the show were well worth the effort...
>   After *days of* travelling though the arid desert, we finally found water...